# Satire source is enough to close a question?

Tags: discussion

I have a question : [No man (or woman) is an island](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/386593/no-man-or-woman-is-an-island)

My basic question is whether the following two sentences are correct:

> “No man is an island.”
>   “No woman is also an island.”

Based on my own thinking and other answers, these seem to be good alternatives for the second sentence:

> “No woman is an island, either.”
>   “Also, no woman is an island.”
>   “No woman is an island, also.”

Now, users have taken the satirical source of the sentences (an article in the New Yorker) and voted to close it. Hence this metaquestion : **Satire source is enough to close a question ?**

When I checked the Description of the close-vote, it is about "explain logically something that was written as satire and which is not intended to make sense syntactically or semantically" : Well, I am not asking to explain. I know what it means.

I am asking how it might be written correctly (say, in a newspaper, in some non-satirical way) so I think the close votes are not appropriate.

Comment: There is someone, I don't who, maybe it's two individuals, but they are  casting their votes to close so many questions that the review queue is rising "vertiginously".

Comment: The question has now been placed on hold. I've cast my vote to reopen it. What difference does it make whether it's satirical or not, it's still a legitimate question about the English language.

Comment: I think you've done a few things strangely in your question1) You've misunderstood the import of the NY article. It's about poorly written essays ('haha young people cant write well') 2) You've misunderstood the particular example, how the two sentences are funny because of the syntax gaffe 3) You haven't been clear about what you want from an answer. In a comment you say you don't want to have the meaning explained (but then you should have explained the meaning and gaffe in the question) but you want to have it rewritten it correctly (but the 'correct' meaning you want unclear).

Comment: I voted to reopen, but the question needs to be edited to clarify.

Comment: Mitch & @Mari-LouA , thanks for getting it reopened !

Comment: @Mitch , the meaning was that both men and women are not islands, but the "gaffe" I was not fully aware of; but I did get the feeling that something was wrong and hence posted the question to see how it could be rewritten without the "gaffe" or awkwardness. Ok, I will try to simplify it.

Comment: I have read OP's original question and did not find it ambiguous by any means, but actually quite clear that he is asking about the proper construction of such a sentence and not about the satirical article itself. With due respect to all learned members, I think the move to close it as off topic was dull and needless; therefore I appreciate the sensible move to get it reopened.

Comment: Kind vote-empowered members with the best of intentions: our shared basic aim is to clear confusion and enlighten the questioner, so please vote to close any question **only if** it is **absolutely necessary** to do so!

Comment: @Mitch You had it right the first time, IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

The source doesn't matter; we have to consider the question solely on its merits. If the question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it will be closed.

There may be exceptional cases once in a while, and for those questions, the senior members will vote to close, then later other members may vote to reopen, and later get closed, reopened, closed, and so on it may continue.